# Checking for vowels rewrite

Tags: c#, beginner, strings

A few days ago I posted a [little program](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128767/checking-if-a-string-contains-vowels/128789?noredirect=1#comment241458_128789) that would check for vowels within a given word. I have rewritten this program, it can only find vowels in the English language still but, it will now tell you each vowel that is contained in your word, along with a count of how many vowels there are total, it's still not very exciting but I would like some more feedback on what I've done, anything will help:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace CheckForVowels
{
    class Vowels
    {
        static string say(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            return input;
        }
        static string prompt(string input)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            Console.Write($"{input}: ");
            return input;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            say("We will be checking your input to see if it contains vowels or not");
            prompt("Enter a word");

            var count = 0;
            var vowels = Console.ReadLine()
                .Where(c => "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c))
                .Distinct();

            foreach (var vowel in vowels)
            {
                count += 1;
                say($"Your word contains vowel: {vowel}.");
            }

            say($"You have a total of {count} vowels in your word.");

                if (!vowels.Any())
                say($"Your word contains no vowels.");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tested this with no vowels in the word?  I don't think your prompt and the readline will work the way you think it should work.  when you use `write` you stay on the same line, so when you `readline` I think it will read the entire line with the `prompt` string

Comment: @Malachi I have tested it without vowels, it seems to work for me. Are you getting a different issue..?

Comment: I like how you've abstracted away the user interface to helper methods.

Comment: @EricLippert I can't really tell if you're being serious or not..?

Comment: I am serious. Though it is a little weird that those methods are not void returning.

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you. I attempted to get them `void` however this was the only was I could actually get the program to work the way I wanted to (that I'm aware of at this moment.) So I kind of just went with it.

Comment: Just remove the returns and change the return type to void.

Comment: @EricLippert So `return void;`

Comment: No.  No returns at all. Look at `Main`. It's void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should adhere to the following:

- Capitalize method names.
- You don't need `count` variable.
- Don't specify a return type, then not utilize it.

Point (1) and (3) could be rectified:

```
protected static void WriteToConsole(string input)
{
     Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
     Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```

The application code could then be:

```
var vowels = Console.ReadLine().Where(c => "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(c));

if(vowels.Any())
{
     foreach(var vowel in vowels.Distinct())
         WriteToConsole(String.Format("Your sentence contains the following vowel {0}", vowel);

    WriteToConsole(String.Format("Your sentence contains {0} vowels", vowels.Count());
}
else
{
     WriteToConsole("Your sentence doesn't have any vowels.");
}
```

Also to point out, in the other question to avoid duplicate entries an uneeded iterations of repeated vowels, I called `.Distinct`.  This alleviated that, but that would throw off your official count of how many vowels exist within the sentence.  So I call `Distinct` on the loop rather than the initial input.

Also to avoid an unneeded `count` variable, I call `.Count()` on the `IEnumerable`, the feature exist so why not use it?

Comment: What do you mean `count` isn't intentionally used?

Comment: @13aal I modified my answer, you don't need it.  You can simply call `vowels.Count()` rather than create a variable to store the counted index.

Comment: that looks like my answer on the previous question --> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/128778/18427

Comment: Oh! Okay, that's pretty cool, thank you for the answer

Comment: @Malachi Haha, yes it does.

Comment: @Malachi It is quite similar, I didn't think about it like that.  Why did you choose the `Intersect` rather than `Where`?  Yeah, it looks like he used a mix of both our answers.

Comment: @Malachi Your answer used `intersect` while I chose `Where` on that question, as I also answered.  I'm not that familiar with `Intersect`, which is why I was inquiring.

Comment: @Greg I used a mixture of all the answers I was provided, it seemed like a good idea, and I really liked all the answers I was given. The only problem I'm having now is implementing different languages into the program.

Comment: `Intersect` will give a distinct list of matches, `Where` gives a list of matches and may have duplicates. for checking for a list of vowels, I didn't see that we needed to have duplicates, you were doing the distinct in your foreach loop

Comment: I don't know that I would describe it like that @Greg.

Comment: Produces the set intersection of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.